# How to parse multiple tables using BeautifulSoup and save them to a csv file

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I've got a program, almost finished, it is only missing this last part where I'm struggliing. I need to scrap from a lot of webpages (If you need to see an example you need to go on this site http://www.pa.org.mt/page.aspx?n=63C70E73&CaseType=PA and fill the case number with 03732 and case year with 16 and click on the first submit.) the tables on the contentHolder div and write them to a csv file, to get something like this:
Case Status, Status Available, Case Number, PA/03732/16 Location of development: 40 ....
Something like this to all the tables on a webpage and for a lot of webpages.
I wrote some code trying to do this, but it is not working, when I run it, it makes this output on the csv file: https://gyazo.com/6557ac08ad5613a24b5432bfd9e4f2e6 And it doesn't even finishes all the pages because It returns an error in the middle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROJECT\pdfs\converterpluspa.py", line 93, in <module>
    csv.writer(f).writerow(answer)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Heres's my program's entire code so far:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import pickle
import requests
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
import codecs

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print('Current working directory is '+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs')
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, " "))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()

def run(command):
     if platform.system() != 'Windows':
         args = shlex.split(command)
    else:
        args = command
    s = subprocess.Popen(args,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = s.communicate()
    return s.returncode == 0, output, errors

# Change this to your PDF file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs'
if not os.path.isdir(base_directory):
    print "%s is not a directory" % base_directory
    exit(1)
 # Change this to your pdf2htmlEX executable location
bin_path = 'C:\\Python27\\pdfminer-20140328\\tools\\pdf2txt.py'
if not os.path.isfile(bin_path):
    print "Could not find %s" % bin_path
    exit(1)
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a PDF file
        if not file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        # Convert your PDF to HTML here
        args = (bin_path, file_name, file_path)
        success, output, errors = run("python %s -o %s.html %s " %args)
        if not success:
            print "Could not convert %s to HTML" % file_path
            print "%s" % errors
htmls_path = 'C:\\PROJECT'
with open ('score.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(htmls_path):
        for file_name in file_name_list:
            if not file_name.endswith('.html'):
                continue
            with open(file_name) as markup:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
                text = soup.get_text()
                match = re.findall("PA/(\S*)", text)#To remove the names that appear, just remove the last (\S*), to add them is just add the (\S*), before it there was a \s*
                print(match)
                writer.writerow(match)
                 for item in match:
                    data = item.split('/')
                    case_number = data[0]
                    case_year = data[1]

                browser = RoboBrowser()
                browser.open('http://www.pa.org.mt/page.aspx?n=63C70E73&CaseType=PA')
                form = browser.get_forms()[0]  # Get the first form on the page
                form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseNo'].value = case_number
                form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseYear'].value = case_year

                browser.submit_form(form, submit=form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$btnSubmit'])

                # Use BeautifulSoup to parse this data
                answer = browser.response.text
                print(answer)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(answer)
                #print soup.prettify()
                status = soup.select('#Table1')
                print (status)
                with codecs.open('file_output.csv', 'a', encoding ='utf-8') as f:
                  for tag in soup.select("#Table1"):
                    csv.writer(f).writerow(answer)
```

EDIT: I tried to change the last line to `csv.writer(f).writerow(answer.encode("utf-8"))` and it didn't worked, it printed another error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROJECT\pdfs\converterpluspa.py", line 93, in <module>
    csv.writer(f).writerow(answer.encode("utf-8"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 706, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 369, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 25496: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And nothing channged on the final csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your output using UTF-8. Change the last line to:

```
csv.writer(f, encoding="utf-8").writerow(answer.encode("utf-8"))
```

Also change the import from `import csv` to `import unicodecsv as csv`

Comment: I tried it and it didn't worked I updated my question so you can see better what gone wrong

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the error that you've posted. Please give it a try now.

Comment: Now it says that unicodecsv isn't a module, it doesn't exist, keepin mind i'm using python 2.7